# How to use switch-case using getpackagename in android

Tags: java, android

We have using three project code is same but package name is different and then API also different URL,we have using switch-case get package Name based, we want get that particular case URL and then call the URL in another class. can you help me

```
public class AllChanges extends Application {

    public static Context context;
    public static String getPackageName() {
            return context.getPackageName();
    }

    public String url( ) {
        switch (getPackageName()){
            case "com.product.packagename1":
                Url  = "http://google.com";

            case "com.product.packagename2":
                Url  = "http://stackoverflow,com";

            case "com.product.packagename3":
                Url  = "http://facebook.com";

            case "com.product.packagename4":
                Url  = "http://bing.com";

            case "com.product.packagename5":
                Url  = "http://gmail.google.com";

        }

        return Url;
    }

    public static String Url = url();

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: didn't get packagename swich case is not working

Comment: Debug getPackage() api's return value and pas it to swtich statement. Moreover you are not assigning anything to context in your class. Hope you can use the getApplicationContext() and then try to use the context.

Comment: i tried application is stopped this error is coming Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    }

Comment: i tried this code didn't get pakagename

Comment: Where is your onCreate() Method. Is this an android Activity or a normal class. Because when onCreate() is getting called you will get a package name through context

Comment: public String getPackageName(Context context) {
        return context.getPackageName();
    }

Comment: this line is correct

Comment: `swich case is not working` - how exactly it is not working?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the Context is available and assigned. Also the Application class extends Context so it has a getPackageName() Function.

**Quick Solution:**

```
public class AllChanges  extends Application {

public static String urlString;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    urlString = getUrl();
}

public String getUrl( ) {
    switch (getPackageName()){
        case "com.product.packagename1":
            return "http://google.com";

        case "com.product.packagename2":
            return "http://stackoverflow,com";

        case "com.product.packagename3":
            return "http://facebook.com";

        case "com.product.packagename4":
            return "http://bing.com";

        case "com.product.packagename5":
            return "http://gmail.google.com";

    }
    return null;
}

}
```

---

**Recommendation:**

A cleaner and my reccomended solution is to use different build flavours and different resource folders, which sould contain the specific urls.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, using a case does not seem like the proper solution. If what you want to do is actually map URLs, then use a map.

```
import java.util.HashMap;


public class UrlMappingExample {
    private static final HashMap<String,String> urlMappings = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        urlMappings.put("com.product.packagename1", "http://google.com");
        urlMappings.put("com.product.packagename2", "http://stackoverflow,com");
        urlMappings.put("com.product.packagename3", "http://facebook.com");
        urlMappings.put("com.product.packagename4", "http://bing.com");
    }

    public static String resolve(String url) {
        return urlMappings.containsKey(url)? urlMappings.get(url) : null;
    }
}
```